# Использование тегов в textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать также, как и в Evernote:
Жирный текст в textarea, когда нажала на кнопку, а когда ввела текст`<b>тест</b>`  - не получалось?
[image: Пример в evernote]

Comment: contenteditable

Comment: А как мне это должно помочь?) Это ведь атрибут, который позволяет в любом диве писать, как в textarea, но он не решает мой вопрос

Comment: contenteditable позволяет не просто писать, а html-редактировать в любом блоке, КРОМЕ `<textarea>`. К нему существует специальный метод `execCommand` с помощью которого можно реализовать практически полноценый редактор

Comment: Всё равно не получила ответ на свой вопрос..
При написании этого атрибута, у меня всё равно получается так-же, то есть 
вместо жирного текста получаю - <b>текст</b>

Comment: То есть, вам нужно, чтобы при написании тега в блоке, он в реальном времени преобразовывался в html-сущность? Это только средствами js - отслеживать изменения контента блока и постоянно переинсертировать весь контент с помощью, например, `innerHTML` либо в этот же блок (при условии, конечно, что это будет тот же contenteditable `div`, скажем), либо в какой-либо другой, специально предназначенный для препросмотра.

Comment: Да-да, именно так. Я пыталась сделать через `oninput` и `onchange`, но не получилось. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку - вставлялся тег, например `<b>`, а при повторном нажатии - вставлялся конец тега - `</b>`, но при этом не менялся текст, который написан, как тег, но текст